# Auto-recalculating M-values using ArcPy in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, m-values

I have M-enabled polylines, these lines are calibrated using different calibration points and some even start from zero. I want to drop existing M-values and then want to assign distance as M-value.

I can do this in ArcMap as you can see in the images below:

Dropping existing M-values.

[image: Drop Measures]

Recalculating using Set as Distance.

[image: Recalculate M-values based on Distance]

I have many such polylines and I am trying to automate it using ***arcpy*** but could not find anything related to this.

Note: There is a tool  "Create Route", but it requires ***coordinate_priority*** which changes the direction of the line. I need to recalibrate line based on distance with direction preserved.

Comment: Feature to vertices (both ends). Use orig_fid to transfer line length to every even point. Use points to calibrate routes.  Set measure to 0 for odd points

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use the "Create Route" Tool, it is intended for creating new route but it will probably work on existing route by just updating the M value (note that it will create a new layer)

[The help page of the tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/linear-ref-toolbox/create-routes.htm) has example on how to use it in a python script (you could also use it directly from the tool box)

Comment: This creates route on above that line, it does not change the M-value of the actual line.

Comment: If you what you choose as route ID was a unique ID you now have an identical set of polyline the only difference being the that the M value is set to length. So you can replace your original set by the new one or delete the original polyline and load the new one...

Comment: Its changing the direction of the line.

Answer (score 0):

I know you've tagged this as `arcpy` but this could be solved with a little VBA and the ArcObjects interface [IMSegmentation3](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IMSegmentation3.htm). I would preselect the lines you want to recalibrate and then  update the geometries in the mxd with some VBA.

I know ArcObjects can be exposed to python using `comtypes`, but I've never done that as I know how to code in VBA which is quicker for me.